# azure insight - changing color of bar results

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Im using Azue insight in our project at work .

I have created a char bar report , I wanted to know if i can change the color of the bars?

by default we get an orange and blue column color .  and it's funny but the failed bar clolored blue , and the succsess colored orange .

[image]

can someone help me out ?

is there a way to change the bar colors?

Thank you ,

Oded Kessler

Comment: Are you using KQL?

Comment: Yes I'm using KQL , but I don't know of  a way to change the bar color using KQL .. do u ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to change the colors in Azure Log Analytics, these colors are by default:

[image]

If you want to customize colors you can use **`Azure Workbooks`** where you can change the colors and apply:

[image]

Here you can customize colors.